# Probability / prediction whether an order can be placed next week

Tags: probability, statistics

thank you in advance for any advice.

Example:
All orders for our services are stochastic.
Suppose a customer created an orders in 2020 (January through August) on the following days:

Monday     1

Tuesday    6

Wednesday  10

Thursday   13

Friday     8

(I also have a timeline list, but I don't know if it is needed in this example).

So he had 173 workdays to place the orders.
This year there is 52&53 of these workdays.

Is it possible to determine in some way the probability / odds / prediction whether an order can be placed next week for individual days? For which day, what is the probability of order creation?

My thoughts:
I don't know if I just think it's a difficult problem or I'm just looking for complexity.

The problem is that it is really not possible to say whether a customer will order something in a given week or not. He can make several orders a day, a week, but he doesn't have to.

I simply imagine that the forecast is for the corresponding day in the coming week.

I was wondering if the probability that the customer will place an order on Thursday is 13/53 = 0.25 = 25% (ie the number of orders this year / the number of all Thursdays).
But here I think I can't count on Thursdays that haven't happened yet in the year.

Will it not be 13/35 = 0.37 = 37% (ie the number of orders this year / the number of Thursdays in the observed period)?

I will be happy for your input, ideas and suggestions, I will go on to study further.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking (what does "$52\,\&\,53$ workdays" mean?) but I doubt there is enough information here to answer your question.If you want to, you can guess that last year's pattern will hold going forward,   And I think you could make a strong case for claiming that Wednesday and Thursday are likely to be your big order days, but I wouldn't expect any strong pattern to be consistent.

Comment: @lulu This year (2020) have 52 Mondays, Tuesday & Frid. and 53 Wednesday & Thursday. Or Jan-August it is 35 working days.

Just wanted to be sure about my thinking, I was trying to find some sort of seasonality, but no luck in that area too...